# How to remove the empty rows in a dataframe and, at the same time, the corresponding rows go away in another dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two dataframes, one of which (`df_B`) has empty rows:

```
df_A = data.frame(Text = c("Hello World", "Hello", "Hello Hello Hello", "Hey Ciao Hi"), stringsAsFactors = F)

               Text
1       Hello World
2             Hello
3 Hello Hello Hello
4       Hey Ciao Hi


df_B = data.frame(Text = c("", "Why not asking SE for a solution", "SE will fix this", ""), stringsAsFactors = F)

                             Text
1                                 
2 Why not asking SE for a solution
3                 SE will fix this
4
```

I would like to remove the empty rows of `df_B`and at the same time the corresponding rows of `df_A`. This what I would like to get:

```
# df_A

               Text

2             Hello
3 Hello Hello Hello


# df_B

                             Text

2 Why not asking SE for a solution
3                 SE will fix this
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple as this

```
newB<-df_B[df_B$Text != "",]
newA<-df_A[df_B$Text != "",]
```

second option using
magrittr and dplyr

```
df_B%>%filter(df_B$Text != "")
df_A%>%filter(df_B$Text != "")
```